# Unable to understand VBScript set of code

Tags: c#, vbscript, tridion

I need to convert some VBScript code to C# 2.0, below is the VBScript code, which needs to be converted to c#.

```
' Component Template titles handled by the summary templates
FeaturedCT = "Featured Summary"
SummaryCT = "Summary"

' Set the looping variables on the first component presentation
If IsFirstComponent = 0 Then
    IsFirstComponent = 1

    ' Start out left handed by default
    IsLeftHand = True

    matchCount = 0
    Dim components()
    ReDim components(Page.ComponentPresentations.Count)

    ' Build a list of all the matching component presentations to be rendered out as summaries
    For Each objCP In Page.ComponentPresentations
        ' Is this a Summary component template?
        If objCP.ComponentTemplateTitle = SummaryCT Or objCP.ComponentTemplateTitle = FeaturedCT Then
            ' Check if this object should be included based on its approval status
            If staging Or getFieldValue(objCP.Component.MetadataFields("ApprovalStatus"), "") = "" Then
                If getFieldValue(objCP.Component.MetadataFields("EndDate"), "") <> "" Then
                    If getDateSerial(objCP.Component.MetadataFields("EndDate").Value(1), False) > getDateSerial(Now, False) Then
                        Set components(matchCount) = objCP
                        matchCount = matchCount + 1
                    End If
                Else
                    Set components(matchCount) = objCP
                    matchCount = matchCount + 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ' Resize the array to the amount of matches
    ReDim Preserve components(matchCount)
End If

For i = 0 to UBound(components) - 1
    ' Determine which component to render from the pre-selected array
    If components(i).ComponentID = Component.ID And components(i).OrdinalPosition = ComponentPresentation.OrdinalPosition Then
        ' Featured summary is always left aligned and causes all other items to be right-aligned
        If ComponentPresentation.ComponentTemplateTitle = FeaturedCT Then
            HasFeaturedSummary = 1
            IsLeftHand = True           
        End If

        Call RenderEntry(components, i)

        ' If a featured summary was previously present all following items are right-aligned
        If HasFeaturedSummary = 1 Then
            IsLeftHand = False
        Else
            ' Update the left-handed status
            UpdatePositioning
        End If

        If i = UBound(Components) - 1 Then
            WriteOut "<div class=""clearBoth""></div>"
        End If
    End If
Next
```

And below is the code which is attempted by me in c#.

```
  public string RenderSummaryCT()
    {
        string FeaturedCT = "Featured Summary CT";
        string SummaryCT = "Summary CT";
        int IsFirstComponent = 0;
        string result = string.Empty;
        int hasFeaturedSummary = 0;
        Component comp = null;
        bool IsLeftHand = false;
        StringBuilder sbOutput = new StringBuilder();

        List<tc.ComponentPresentation> cmp = new List<tc.ComponentPresentation>();

        if (IsFirstComponent == 0)
        {
            IsFirstComponent = 1;
            IsLeftHand = true;

            //m_Logger.Info("CMP Array-" + cmp.Count);
            foreach (tc.ComponentPresentation objCMP in m_Page.ComponentPresentations)
            {
                if ((objCMP.ComponentTemplate.Title == SummaryCT) || (objCMP.ComponentTemplate.Title == FeaturedCT))
                {
                    comp = objCMP.Component;
                    string approvalStatus = string.Empty;
                    string endDate = string.Empty;

                    if (comp.Metadata != null)
                    {
                        ItemFields compItemfields = new ItemFields(comp.Metadata, comp.MetadataSchema);
                        approvalStatus = th.GetSingleStringValue("ApprovalStatus", compItemfields);
                        endDate = th.GetSingleStringValue("EndDate", compItemfields);
                    }
                    if ((baseutility.GetStagingConstantValue(m_Engine, m_Package)) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(approvalStatus)))
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate))
                        {
                            DateTime eDate = Convert.ToDateTime(baseutility.GetDateSerial(Convert.ToDateTime(endDate), false));
                            DateTime currentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(baseutility.GetDateSerial(DateTime.Now, false));
                            if ((eDate) > (currentDate))
                            {
                                cmp.Add(objCMP);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmp.Add(objCMP);
                            //m_Logger.Info("2. Adding cmp: " + maxCount.ToString() + "-- " + cmp[maxCount].Component.Title);                              
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        bool lastFlag = false;
        int cnt = 0;
        int totalLength = cmp.Count;

        foreach (tc.ComponentPresentation cm in cmp)
        {
            m_Logger.Info(cm.Component.Id + "--" + m_Component.Id);

            m_Logger.Info(cnt + "--" + totalLength);

            if (cm.Component.Id == m_Component.Id)
            {
                if (cm.ComponentTemplate.Title == FeaturedCT)
                {
                    m_Logger.Info("inside featured CT");
                    hasFeaturedSummary = 1;
                    IsLeftHand = true;
                }
                sbOutput.Append("" + SummaryBase.SummaryHelper.RenderEntry(cmp, cnt, IsLeftHand, lastFlag));

                m_Logger.Info("IsLeftHand -: " + IsLeftHand.ToString());

                if (hasFeaturedSummary == 1)
                {
                    IsLeftHand = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //sbOutput.Append("" + SummaryBase.SummaryHelper.UpdatePositioning(IsLeftHand));
                    if (IsLeftHand)
                    {
                        IsLeftHand = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //m_Logger.Info("UpdatePositioning");
                        sbOutput.Append("<div class=\"clearBoth\"></div>");
                        IsLeftHand = true;
                    }
                }

                m_Logger.Info("CMP Title -: " + cm.Component.Title);

                cnt = cnt + 1;
                if (totalLength == cnt)
                {
                    m_Logger.Info("cnt-" + cnt);
                    lastFlag = true;
                }
                if (lastFlag)
                {
                    sbOutput.Append(" <div class=\"clearBoth\"></div>");
                }
            }
        }

        return sbOutput.ToString();
    }
```

I am sure there is something wrong, can you please suggest the suitable logic using above VBScript logic.

Comment: It would be helpful to know why you think it's wrong - you get the wrong set of pages, or in the wrong places, or which part of the code you suspect is wrong, etc. As-is you're asking for someone to work through your code and verify the whole thing for you.

Comment: @Rup, ok in that case I am sorry, but can you check the code written under the "For i = 0 to UBound(components) - 1", there only I am getting confused..thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's more to this than just "Converting VBScript to .NET", you're also moving from COM-based Tridion Object Model, to the .NET TOM - which works quite differently.

My recommendation here would be to take a very analytic view to it:

1. Break down your code and write the logic on paper first
2. Try to understand *why* it needs to happen and if it should still be the case

This should make it a lot easier for you to rewrite the code later on.

I would certainly take this opportunity to rewrite parts of it so it makes more sense - like having the IsFirstComponent variable converted to a boolean instead of an int, and remove all HTML from your c# code (not that you have much in there, but the next person working on this code would probably like to know that the HTML is not being created by some assembly "hidden" somewhere on your server).

I'll try to take a look at this VBScript later, but I think that understanding really what the code does may be more important at this point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I appreciate your thinking, the problem is with time, our project needs to up with .Net Templating as soon as possible, its a big tridion implementation and in our first phase implementation we are targeting just the logic conversion to .NET and in next phase will look in to what needs to be changed or not. I hope this makes you clear....Well thanks again and keep posting your good answers.

Comment: Got it. Unfortunately in this case, you can't just translate the VBScript to .NET, since there is no "OrdinalPosition" in a .NET list. You'll probably need to loop through the Components collection and check if page.ComponentPresentations[i].Component.Id matches Components[i].Id

Comment: As Nuno says, writing the logic down for this code on paper is a good idea.  However, I would also do this exercise for all of the major pieces of templating functionality.  Viewed together this should allow you to identify common pieces of templating code and build a better templating solution (allowing code re-use, simpler debugging, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I can't see what is being done with the ordinalPosition. My guess is that as you call render on each component presentation, the current values of Component and ComponentPresentation are updated. (In old-style templating, components and pages share the same render stack.) But I'm guessing here, and I'm still not sure what the intended logic is. @Nuno - the Components collection won't usually be updated after it's populated from Page.ComponentPresentations in "Extract Components From Page" so I doubt if the black magic will port so easily.

So Manu - you need to check what the functional spec for this feature is. It may be that the idea is simply to test whether there is a Featured Summary component presentation anywhere at all in the list, and if so, put this on the left and the rest on the right. (If this is so, then it's some pretty tortuous logic to get there.) In practice, you might have to review the existing pages that use this template, see how they function, and commit to supporting only those pages in your port.

(You might also want to review what that workflow code is for. Maybe configuring a minimum approval status on your live target would enable you to remove this code.)

I wholeheartedly endorse Nuno's original suggestion to take the opportunity to re-write some things. Even with your time constraints, you will never be successful in getting the logic right unless you understand the problem, and then implement the code. Seriously - having unmaintainable code like this will only hurt more when you run up against a hard deadline.

Processing different kinds of component presentations is a common requirement in Tridion page templates. The templating idiom is very different in compound templating, but when done correctly, it is much easier to understand than the approach shown here. There is a [base class available at the Tridion practice project](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/PartitionComponentPresentations) which you may find helpful when you have the chance to write the code idiomatically rather than doing a line-by-line port.